# onload, addevenlistener not work in child window in firefox

Tags: javascript

There is an extension for Firefox, file contentz.js contains the following code:

```
var lock = false;

window.onload = async function() {
  if (!lock) {
    lock = true;
    emulate();
  }
}

async function emulate() {
  var urlz = "https://example.com";
  var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    newWin = window.open(urlz + "/page1.html", "hello", "width=800,height=600");

    var timerId;

    newWin.addEventListener("load", analyze_it); //eventlistener
    function analyze_it() {
      alert("test");
      resolve("Success!");
    } //func for event listener
  })
}
```

In the extension for chrome, this code works without problems

firefox extension:
This code returns an error to console -  DOMException: "Permission denied to access property "addEventListener" on cross-origin object"
at the same time the parent window has the same domain - **example.com**!
What to do with it, how to make it work?

my manifest for firefox ext:

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "extens_ff",
  "version": "2.2",

  "description": "Search..",
  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/icon.png"
  },

  "applications": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "extens@future.com",
      "strict_min_version": "45.0"
    }
  },



    "permissions": 
[ "activeTab","tabs","unlimitedStorage","storage", "https://*.example.com/"],

  "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icons/icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popupz.html"
    },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.example.com/*"],
      "js": ["contentz.js"]
    }
  ]

}
```

Comment: Adding listener to window open is problematic and before it is loaded location may not have proper final value. I did such things from HTA using interval and checking all needed properties (window, document, body, etc.).

Comment: @Tom returns to any requested item - Permission denied